# After Installation RVM and Ruby 1.9.3 every Bash path change RVM Initialization Script is printed

Tags: ruby, bash, osx-lion, rvm

I installed the latest RVM - Ruby Version Manager - and installed Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3 on OSX Lion with XCode 4.3.3 using clang `rvm install 1.9.3 --reconfigure --debug -C --enable-pthread --with-gcc=clang` as the regular way did not work due to a GCC error. I did get one error `clang: error: unsupported option '--with-libyaml`, but Ruby 1.9.3 worked and I could run WPScan that needs at least 1.9.2 . 
But now every time I run a command to change folder such as `cd` I get a long Bash script printed related to RVM - see http://pastebin.com/UAm38Vcm and:
[image: Bash Display after cd command].

How can I stop it from doing that?

**Update I**

Added a comment at RVM at Github as well https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1039 , but as that issue is not 100% related and as I need this solved as soon as possible I opened a thread here with more data.

**Update II**

I realized the RVM Initialization script is the one that is being printed: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/blob/master/scripts/initialize . No idea why though..

**Update IV**

My `.bashrc`

```
# define aliases
alias sudo='sudo '
#alias ruby='ruby1.9'
alias apacherestart='sudo apachectl -k restart'

# define hist properties
HISTFILESIZE=1000000000
HISTSIZE=1000000

# define path to programs
PATH=/opt/local/bin:opt/local/sbin:/opt/subversion/bin:/opt/local/apache2/bin/:/opt/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/bin:$PATH

# define manpath
MANPATH=/opt/local/share/man:$MANPATH

# export env vars
export HISTFILESIZE HISTSIZE PATH MANPATH
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

My `.bash_profile`

```
source ~/.bashrc
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

Comment: This only happens for `cd` and not other commands? If you open a new terminal, does it do it, too? What do `echo "$PS1"` and `echo "$PROMPT_COMMAND"` output? What does `type -a cd` say?

Comment: @DennisWilliamson `echo "$PS1"
echo "$PS1"
\h:\W \u\$ 
update_terminal_cwd;`
and `echo "$PROMPT_COMMAND"
echo "$PROMPT_COMMAND"
update_terminal_cwd; 
update_terminal_cwd;` Typing `type -a cd` prints the whole RVM script.

Comment: When I open a new terminal it does not happen. I will just see `Last login: Sat Jul 14 12:13:00 on ttys001
You have new mail.
jaspersmbp:~ jasper$ `

Comment: Try `unset -f cd` or `unalias cd`.

Comment: If `type -a cd` outputs anything other than "cd is a shell builtin" then `cd` is aliased or a function has been created named "cd" (it's possible on some systems that it will also output a filesystem location but you can ignore that).

Comment: `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*` was added to `.bash_profile` . This must be part of the issue, but was added by RVM

Comment: Since it doesn't happen in a new terminal, you don't need to worry about startup files like `.bashrc` and thus the question is essentially moot. Close the terminal and open a new one. Done.

Comment: See updated question with `.bash_profile`. Is it caused by the line added by RVM? RVM did not add it there for no reason..

Comment: What's in `$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm`? See my previous comment.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13877/discussion-between-rhand-and-dennis-williamson)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `cd` command has somehow become aliased or a function has been created named "cd".

You can undo those with either:

```
unalias cd
```

or

```
unset -f cd
```

Comment: Thanks for all the comments and tips. Somehow cd got aliased. All good now after I opened a new terminal. Also was able to load Ruby of choice again using `rvm use 1.9.3`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to revert temporarily with

```
unalias cd
```

It appears that you will need to figure out what was changed in your `.bashrc` and revert all those changes.  If the installation script is at all sanely written, it should have made backups, or document somehow what was changed.

Comment: `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*` was added to `.bash_profile` which is needed to work with RVM. Dennis and you mention `unalias cd` . Not sure how that helps.. `.bashrc` had no changes except for the commenting of a ruby alias `#alias ruby='ruby1.9'`

Comment: `.rvm/scripts/rvm` apparently includes functionality to alias out `cd`. The line from `.bash_profile` is what you need to remove, yes.